# Generic Dao and service Layer

Tags: java, dao

I am going to design a DAO layer for my application. My focus is that Services just calls DAO which is independent of underlaying implementation.

```
    public interface GenericSearchDao{
        List getAll();
        List getByQuery(String query);
}

public class UserJdbcSearch implements GenericSearchDao{

        public List getAll(){
                // Get all users;
        }

        List getByQuery(String query){
                // Get users by query;
        }

}

public class UserFileSystemSearch implements GenericSearchDao{

        public List getAll(){
                // Get all users from file system;
        }


        List getByQuery(String query){
                // Get users by query[this leads to invalid operation];
        }
}

public userService {

        private GenericSearchDao dao = new UserFileSystemSearch();

        public List getUsers(){
                rturn dao.getAll();
        }

         public List getByQuery(String query){
               return  dao.getByQuery(query);
        }
}
```

**Help Required:**

What should I do to get rid from 'getByQuery(query)' specific implementaions because datastore can be RDBMS, filesystem, FTP etc.

How should I design my Dao layer generically?

If any one says "remove the getByQuery() from GenericSearchDao" then what should i do in the case where i need data specific to business operation for eg : user with roles , user with products etc..

Comment: Copypaste bug! `Stirng`.

Answer (score 0):

> *What should I do to get rid from 'getByQuery(query)' specific implementaions because datastore can be RDBMS, filesystem, FTP etc.*

You don't,  you just need to provide "generic" query, for instance "name = a" may perform a query in a databae, or look for a file named "a" or pretty much anything else.

Comment: Sir, Don't you think this leads to a small query language i am going to develop for each underlying implementaion :)

Answer (score 0):

What information do you plan to pass in the "query" parameter ? SQL ? I'd replace the String parameter with something business-specific, maybe a small class wiht fields like "name", "surname", etc. The underlying implementation will transform it into SQL, or remote service calls, or other implementation-specific magic.

Comment: I appriciate your answer. Your answer leads to a small query language so i can interpret it according to underlying implementation. But i don't want to invent this query language. I think there is a option, Dao Pattern, which i should realize. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You may find this approach useful http://www.bejug.org/confluenceBeJUG/display/BeJUG/Generic+DAO+example

Comment: The implementation in that link is completely tied to hibernate (have a look at the import statements). There are better solutions out there. This one for example: http://codeblock.engio.net/?p=180

Answer (score 0):

For specific impl just throw "UnsupportedOperationException". Good Generic dao implementation can be found here http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/ - I also could adjust the source code to work with hibernate 4 & spring 3

Answer (score -1):

Hey, check this site [DAO Implementation](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html). There are some DAO implementations with different Design patterns. I think DAO with Abstact factory would be suitable for you.

Comment: Yes, but the problem in this case is currently i have one dao and its impl but in future i can have 30 dao's and its 30 impl's ... I need to minimize or kill this repeatation also need to decouple Service with DAO and its underlaying implementaion.

Comment: Have a look at http://codeblock.engio.net/?p=180. I present a solution that uses technology agnostic implementations of different storage technologies as underlying mechanism for domain specific DAOs.